# Enviar opcion y parametro ajax para ejecutar funcion javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estoy haciendo un sistema de cobro de cuotas, y tengo el siguiente problema.
Cuando elijo el nombre del socio en un combo, necesito saber el valor de la cuota de ese socio que depende de la categoria a la que pertenece y una vez seleccionado el socio en el combobox, muestra el valor de la cuota en un text. lo que hago es lo siguiente

vista/script/cuotasocio.js

```
$('#idsocio').on('change', function() {
        var valorcuota; //guardara el futuro valor cuota
  var idpersona = $(this).val(); //obtiene id socio para ver que cat es
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:'../ajax/cuotasocio.php?op=obtenercuota', // nombre de la funcion 
    dataType: "html",
    data: idpersona,
    async : false,
    success: function(respuesta) {
      valorcuota =  respuesta; //repuesta
    },
  });

  //limpia el input
  $('#valorcuota').val('');
  //agrega valor
  $('#valorcuota').val(valorcuota);
})
```

ajax/cuotasocio.php

```
<?php 
require_once "../modelos/CuotaSocio.php";

$cuotasocio=new CuotaSocio();

$idcuotasocio=isset($_POST["idcuotasocio"])? limpiarCadena($_POST["idcuotasocio"]):"";
$fecha_hora=isset($_POST["fecha_hora"])? limpiarCadena($_POST["fecha_hora"]):"";
$recargo=isset($_POST["recargo"])? limpiarCadena($_POST["recargo"]):"";
$descuento=isset($_POST["descuento"])? limpiarCadena($_POST["descuento"]):"";

$idpersona=isset($_POST["idpersona"])? limpiarCadena($_POST["idpersona"]):"";

switch ($_GET["op"]) {
    case 'guardaryeditar':
    if (empty($idcuotasocio)) {
        $rspta=$cuotasocio->insertar($idpersona,$fecha_hora,$recargo,$descuento);
        echo $rspta ? "Datos registrados correctamente" : "No se pudo registrar los datos";
    }else{
         $rspta=$cuotasocio->editar($idpersona,$fecha_hora,$recargo,$descuento);
        echo $rspta ? "Datos actualizados correctamente" : "No se pudo actualizar los datos";
    }
        break;
    
    case 'obtenercuota':
        $rspta=$cuotasocio->obtenercuota($idpersona);
        echo json_encode($rspta);
        break;
```

modelo/CuotaSocio.php

```
require "../config/Conexion.php";
class CuotaSocio{

    //implementamos nuestro constructor
public function __construct(){

}

public function obtenercuota($idpersona){
    $sql="SELECT c.valor_cuota  FROM categoria c join persona p on c.idcategoria = p.idcategoria WHERE p.idpersona = '$idpersona'";
    return ejecutarConsultaSimpleFila($sql);
}
```

vista/cuotasocio.php

```
<form action="" name="formulario" id="formulario" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-md-8 col-xs-12">
      <label for="">Socio(*):</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="idcuotasocio" id="idcuotasocio">
      <select name="idsocio" id="idsocio" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" required>
       
     </select>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-6">
      <label for="">Valor Cuota: </label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="valorcuota" id="valorcuota">
    </div>
....
```

Si se les ocurre algo mas simpre tambien sera bienvenido.. Gracias